wlink to create an executable from obj files and libraries
I got the newest version of WATCOMs wlink from github (V2.0 29.04.2024, https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2) and djgpp-mingw-gcc1220-standalone from github too (https://github.com/andrewwutw/build-djgpp).
So I tried to compile this code (test.c) :
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}

By the following command:
gcc test.c -w -freestanding -c -o test.o

Then I wanted to create an executable from that test.o file by using wlink
So I did that:
wlink file test.o file lib/libmsvcrt.a

(libmsvcrt.a is a library I got from mingw which provides printf function as far as I know)
Executing these commands does not output any exceptions, but no executable has been created by wlink. Wlink prints this:
Open Watcom Linker...
Copyright...
Portions Copyright...
Source code is available under...
See https://github...
loading object files

Thats it, no errors. If I do the same but with this code (another version of test.c):
int main(){
  return 0;
}

and the same steps, but
wlink file test.o

It works fine and test.exe is been generated. So it seems that the .a libraries here is the problem. How can i fix it?
This is just a minimal example, the real project is much bigger, so i think getting all the object files from that .a file via
ar xv libmsvcrt.a 

And searching for all .o files of all the standard c functions I am using and including them while linking by hand doesn't seem right to me, even though this could work if I put a lot of time and effort into it.

From a quick glance at the manual
I think you should replace wlink file test.o file lib/libmsvcrt.a with wlink file test.o,lib/libmsvcrt.a,
or better wlink file test.o file library lib/libmsvcrt.a
Each file option supercedes rather than extends any previous file option, so your command would
only input libmsvcrt.a to the linkage, from which no members would be linked because no object files
have been linked before it that generate references to its members. So in short, nothing is linked.

In any case, such problems will be solved by reading the manual carefully.

This didn't make a change. I also had a look at the manual, is it probably because I am using gnu's .a library files?
